# Rails append the correct model object from has_many association to an array of Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
companies = Company.all
companies.each do |company|
  company.locations = current_user.locations.where(company_id: company.id)
end
return companies
```

Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do above, preferably without looping through all companies?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `includes`, given you did set up relationships properly:

```
companies = Company.all.includes(:locations)
```

I would be concerned here because you dont use any pagination, could lead to tons of data.

There are many articles explaining in [depth like this](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where)

---

After your edit, I'd say

```
companies = Company.all
locations_index = current_user.locations.group_by &:company_id
# no need for where(company_id: companies.map(&:id)) because you query all companies anyway
companies.each do |company|
  company.locations = locations_index.fetch(company.id, [])
end
```

This way, you have 2 queries max.

Comment: I'm sorry, my code example was totally wrong. I corrected it. The difference is this:  company.locations = current_user.locations.where(company_id: company.id). So the locations is an already queried list of activerecord that needs to be appended to the correct company.